# xPath - Why is this exact text selector not working with the data test id?

Tags: xpath, webdriver-io

I have a block of code like so:

```
<ul class="open-menu">
  <span>
    <li data-testid="menu-item" class="menu-item option">
      <svg>...</svg>
      <div>
        <strong>Text Here</strong>
        <small>...</small>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li data-testid="menu-item" class="menu-item option">
      <svg>...</svg>
      <div>
        <strong>Text</strong>
        <small>...</small>
      </div>
    </li>
  </span>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to select a menu item based on exact text like so in the dev tools:

```
$x('.//*[contains(@data-testid, "menu-item") and normalize-space() = "Text"]');
```

But this doesn't seem to be selecting the element. However, when I do:

```
$x('.//*[contains(@data-testid, "menu-item")]');
```

I can see both of the menu items.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that this works:

```
$x('.//*[contains(@class, "menu-item") and normalize-space() = "Text"]');
```

Not sure why using a class in this context works and not a data-testid. How can I get my xpath selector to work with my data-testid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this exact text selector not working

The fact that both `li` elements are matched by the XPath expression
if omitting the condition `normalize-space() = "Text"` is a clue.
`normalize-space()` returns `... Text Here ...` for the first `li`
in the posted XML and `... Text ...` for the second (or some other
content in place of `...` from `div/svg` or `div/small`) causing
`normalize-space() = "Text"` to fail.

In an update you say the same condition succeeds. This has nothing to
do with using `@class` instead of `@data-testid`; it must be triggered
by some content change.

> How can I get my xpath selector to work with my data-testid?

By testing for an exact text match in the `li`'s descendant `strong`
element,

```xsl
.//*[@data-testid = "menu-item" and div/strong = "Text"]
```

which matches the second `li`. Making the test more robust is usually
in order, e.g.

```xsl
.//*[contains(@data-testid,"menu-item") and normalize-space(div/strong) = "Text"]
```

Append `/div/small` or `/descendant::small`, for example, to the XPath
expression to extract just the `small` text.

Answer (score 0):

`data-testid="menu-item"` is matching both the outer `li` elements while text content you are looking for is inside the inner `strong` element.
So, to locate the outer `li` element based on it's `data-testid` attribute value and it's inner `strong` element text value you can use XPath expression like this:

```xsl
//*[contains(@data-testid, "menu-item") and .//normalize-space() = "Text"]
```

Or

```xsl
.//*[contains(@data-testid, "menu-item") and .//*[normalize-space() = "Text"]]
```

I have tested, both expressions are working correctly